# "Informed" badge shown as Next badge, but doesn't exist on this site

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, stackapps, badges

On my profile page, the Informed badge is shown as the next badge to obtain:

[image]

Clicking it even shows a popup with a link to the [Tour](https://stackapps.com/tour) page, but it looks quite different from other SE sites. Looking at the [badge list](https://stackapps.com/help/badges), it seems the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge doesn't even exist. If that is correct, this looks like a bug - the Informed badge should then be removed from the trackable badges for this site.

Comment: Other than this badge and the 3 "Beta" badges, there appear to be no other badge differences between *Stack Apps* and "normal" Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I have been posted the [same bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272748/312043) in MSE on Jan '16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Informed** badge is removed from the "Next badge" tracking. Previously it was listed in the **Available** badges section. Now it is not available under the *Available* or *Bronze* section. So the bug has been fixed recently.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Informed removed from Available section]

Copied from [the MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314266/312043)