# 'Informed' badge doesn't exist on site, but is still being promoted

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, badges

The issue of a non-existent badge being promoted [has been brought up before](https://stackapps.com/questions/6939/informed-badge-shown-as-next-badge-but-doesnt-exist-on-this-site), but the following still happens:

[image]

This will likely disappear once I get another badge (soon after posting this question :), but it's still confusing.

Answer (score 4):

I agree it is weird that you get teased for a badge you're unable to earn.

It is worth mentioning that Stack Apps is a bit special as a Question and Answer site within the Stack Exchange family of sites. We are more an "app store" then a proper Q/A site.

I discussed with a CM and my fellow moderators the options we have. I personally  wondered why our [tour](/tour) has to be different. I feel we could make enough tweaks in wording to make it work. Nevertheless the response from the CM was:

> My guess would be that how SA works is really different so the tour was disabled.

Given that restriction, your bug report is a valid observation and a tad misleading for users that stumble on this site first. I did try to trick the system by manually invoking the right end-point that would give me the badge. Despite a 200 OK response, no badge for me.

So, that leaves us with getting the bug fixed, or at least looked at by a developer. On regular sites this is done by adding the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag to a question. <del>Turned out we don't have that tag here and although I created it, it didn't turn itself into a mod-only status tag. :(</del> [Fixed](https://stackapps.com/q/8980/79306)

That lead to the next exchange with a CM:

> The current tooling doesn't check Stack Apps for the use of the tag [...].
> I've manually sent the report to Jira in the meantime and sent it over to [the team] along with a request for the tag to be converted into a red tag.

So that is where we are now, 6 to 8 weeks after you reported a bug and one bounty later: With some help the bug has landed within a team that is able to either fix the issue or provide an answer why this can't be fixed at this moment.

All we need is some more patience as I'm not given a timeline for when this gets looked at.

Thanks for the report. I'll hand you a virtual informed badge, wear it with pride.

Comment: I'm not sure if I qualify as *a reputable source.* but we'll see when the bounty lands ...

Comment: oops, forgot bout that :)

Answer (score 4):

The button won't be shown after the next production build.

Thanks for the report!

The [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag will become red at the same time.