# Should status-review be made a mod tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta

On most other meta sites, [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) is a moderator tag, however on stack apps (which [is it’s own meta](https://stackapps.com/tags/meta/info)) it is not a moderator tag. Since there is no status-review moderator tag on stack apps, moderators have to directly contact a CM instead of going through the normal workflow of meta sites. One example of this is [shown here](https://stackapps.com/questions/8979)

So, my feature request is to **add the status-review tag as a moderator tag to stack apps**

<sub>Note: Stack Apps already has other mod only status tags, so maybe there is a reason status-review was skipped, or maybe it was an oversight.</sub>

You can see a demonstration of the bug in the tags below.

Edit: now this was tagged (in revision 4) with the moderator tag status review, despite it being added by a normal user. Bugs galore.

Comment: Not a question of should, it will happen as I said here: https://stackapps.com/questions/8930/informed-badge-doesnt-exist-on-site-but-is-still-being-promoted#comment18148_8930

Comment: Compared with other Meta sites, there are two "moderator-only-tag" are missing here, `status-reproduced` and `status-review`

Comment: [This post is under review.](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/6725)

Comment: [tag:status-completed]

Comment: @Anonymous Yep. On a somewhat related note could you please file a bug report about this having a red tag? (I would expect I am question banned on meta)

Comment: It's hard to say whether this is a bug, exactly, just a decision (which is somewhat strange, but removing the tag from every post would be somewhat strange).  And I'm suspended and question banned on MSE, but you could post it here since [Stack Apps is its own meta](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/meta).

Comment: Why do you need a bug report? The tag was created as a normal tag, a user added it to a question, which was legit at the time, a dev flips the bit on the status-review tag so it becomes mod-only from that moment onwards. Let's not create busy work for devs, okay?

Comment: @rene it might not be a worth a devs time, but it is definitely a bug since normal users can’t use mod tags. My understanding was that bugs should be reported no matter how trivial they are. Was I wrong about that?

Comment: You can't file a bug to re-write history.

Comment: @EkadhSingh "My understanding was that bugs should be reported no matter how trivial they are" - that was mine too, before I got question banned on MSE.  Also, this isn't a bug but a design choice, and doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: @EkadhSingh you're free to report bugs but there is [a dark history on SE on that topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694) ... Also note that the FAQ on the Uber-Meta states [*You've found an erroneous or unexpected behavior in the system that needs to be fixed.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-exchange-work/47640#47640). I'm not sure if a trivial bug needs to be fixed. That is a judgement call I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) is now a red moderator-only tag, although this question did keep [my edit](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/6725) even though I'm not a moderator.  [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) remains a regular tag.

Comment: There was a bit flipped on a tag, making it mod-only. Why would it undo an edit?

Comment: @rene It seems strange that I could make an edit that would eventually cause the tag to be added, but I agree with you that it isn't a bug.