# Even though status-review has been made a moderator-only tag, it remains blue on this post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, meta

On [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/8981/79306), [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) is mentioned.  For whatever reason, the tag appeared as blue instead of red.  I've also noticed that it does *not* appear on [this post](https://stackapps.com/q/8980/79306) for some reason.  I thought that editing the post after the tag became moderator-only might turn it back to red, which is why I proposed a [minor edit to the post](https://stackapps.com/suggested-edits/2075).  Sure enough, it changed to red when it was approved, but inactive posts that aren't edited could keep the blue tag indefinitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an edit will fix that.

This is because posts are stored as HTML. At the time the answer was submitted the build wasn't live. Therefor the tag wasn't a mod-only tag yet. It got no special handling. An edit will re-render the HTML and store a new version of the HTML. As the tag has now become mod-only it will render as red.